# Death of Osama Bin Laden -- so who's recording the crowds in NYC and outside the White House?

Tags: crowd, field-recording, historical

Come on folks, don't disappoint me! Chance of a lifetime!! I hope to hear some SoundCloud samples tomorrow morning!

PS> Steve, get out of bed and get down to Pennsylvania Ave!

Comment: LOL I just finished reading the article and was about to post the very same question!!!!!!!! And you beat me by 1 minute! Arghh

Comment: I'm so glad I wasn't the only one who thought of that.

Comment: Man... I was there last week! 

Comment: Reading this Monday morning makes me totally feel like a heel...

Comment: I bet @sepulchra was out at ground zero, can I deflect this attention towards him? lol

Comment: *glowers @Steve*

Comment: hehe j/k.    :-)

Comment: @Steve, all I have to say is: DUDE! YOU SLEPT THROUGH THAT???  ;)

Comment:  @Jay... Words can't express the regret. Next time you hear of a perfect opportunity for stealth recording a crowd of couple 100, late on a Sunday night, a few miles from my house, don't hesitate to **call me**!!!! You've got my number.

Comment: @Utopia I can't blame you, I'm glowering too.

Comment: @Steve How come I don't have your number? BAH

Comment: @Utopia Cause I haven't found any way to contact you.

Comment: @Steve, @Utopia - guys, get a room!

Answer (score 5):

Considering we're all unified through sound I'll really try to leave this as politics free as possible. I really hope this thread doesn't turn into a political debate.

As interesting as it might be historically, I'm not sure how much of it would be usable considering it's all chants of "USA, USA, USA", "We Are The Champions" and "Hey Hey Hey, Goodbye".

Personally I'm not really sure if I'd want proof of such a mass amount of people gloating about someone's death, even considering who it is and the negative impact that this individual has triggered to ripple effect the entire world. Especially when considering how controversial the subject is. Actually, I sort of would want the recording for personal and historical reasons... but I'm not sure I'd ever use it for anything except maybe the lulls between the chants. They're very time/place specific (and very content specific) and you wouldn't really be able to get away with using them in something except a historical documentary without someone noticing considering all the mass media coverage.

To be honest, the whole "gloating" thing kind of really gives me the creeps. It's nice to have (a bit of) closure to the situation and I know what that means to (directly) thousands and potentially billions of people, but it really sucks to know the steps that have been tread to get here and the way "we" as a group, as "Americans" will be perceived for all of the "celebrations" and "gloating". I'm happy about the situation on one hand and sad/disappointed on the other and the best way to sum that up is a quote I found floating around earlier that I thought was a little apropos:

“I’ve never wished a man dead, but I have read some obituaries with great pleasure.”

— Mark Twain

Since I've never had to deal with Public Recording rights then I'm wondering what the legal ramifications of using such a recording would be. I know for images/film you typically have to get a waiver... but I suppose the news gets away with it, so why can't we?

Comment: Appreciate your comments, but I'm not talking politics here - only audio. Back to point: All of these gatherings are happening in public places and by mass amounts of people. I highly doubt that there'd be any legal ramifications for recording and then using said recordings. After all, these are simply crowd recordings; no different than stealth recording in a mall,restaurant or public park. And I tend to disagree with you re. the usefulness of such recordings, as you never know when a project will require a large group of people chanting exactly the thing they are chanting now in NYC and DC.

Comment: @Jay - I didn't think you were talking politics. Just with such a topic that it was bound rear it's ugly face and I was hoping the thread could remain about sound. Yes, I do agree that maybe the opportunity may arise for just those particular chants, I just slightly see that as being a bit of a narrow chance. You do never know with sound though.

Comment: I recede most of my statements about the recordings being unuseable. After checking out even 2-3 of the youtube videos posted from these locations (via peoples video capable phones) they would likely make excellent recordings. I still only like the in-between parts for their versatility as opposed to a ton of chants. A couple chants would be good as well. I'm sure they'll be useful at some place in time for somebody. Maybe they just leave a slightly bad taste in my mouth is all, which is weird... part of why I love doing post is because I can typically separate my emotions from it.

Comment: Regardless of the political aspects... hopefully my post will incite some interesting posts about the inner turmoil and dilemma about certain situations, yes, I'd like to keep the thread politically Opinion Free, but it did open a certain can of worms. Example: I couldn't imagine being one of the videographers at Saddam Husseins hanging. That's just hardcore. Just as there's a certain responsibility placed on them there is one placed on us as well.

Comment: @Jay I'm going to think of this thread when I don't have these recordings for when we do a movie based on Shaun White or some other olympic hokey team or bobsled team and the resultant chant of "USA USA USA" is called for by the director. Heh... Or when I'm doing a boxing movie and I need some outside crowd singing We are the champions. The point I would like to make with Jay's request is that it's REAL. There is something that GENUINELY makes people THRILLED and HAPPY, and by hundreds maybe thousands of people and this is a very rare thing which you can't do on an ADR stage. It was this same 

Comment: idea he had when he asked who was recording the Egyptian riots. Nothing political about it at all - it's a gigantic loop group that will never be created again with the same emotions in an ADR stage.

Answer (score 4):

So, um, yeah. I totally missed the boat on this one. But hopefully my blunder can become  a good lesson for all of us.

Once in a lifetime sound can happen at *any* time. Being prepared with the right gear doesn't amount to a hill of beans if you don't show up to the session. Learn to recognize the opportunities that present themselves and participate in them.

This may mean you have to get out of bed.

Comment: I spent some time trying to find out if there was any celebrating going on in my city, and contemplated just getting in the car and driving around to see what I could find. Didn't end up doing that, and still haven't heard that anything went on locally.


Comment: That's the spirit @Joe! No problem. I don't think many people are THAT serious about giving @Steve a hard time.. At least, I'm not..

Answer (score 1):

I vote for Steve Urban to be the chosen one.

Comment: Damn, called out twice in the same thread. Hate to say it, but I've let my fellow SSD'ers down. Sorry all. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least the AP got it.

Ground Zero, NYC

[youtube]LKPmWsE_G38[/youtube]

White House, Washington, DC

[youtube]K5XVAugy_3I[/youtube]

*hangs head in shame...*